# CSS works good on chrome but not on firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, cross-browser

I have created a page with imgs links
its work great on chrome but i have issue with chrome and firefox. the rest of the site work perfectly only this area not accurate in the 3 web browser.
I tried to search here and over the net but couldnt find any help
http://saggiehaim.net/YSD/projects.html
this is the page with the issue.
as you can see over chrome its working great unlike the other two

Thanks for your time and kind help!

here is my code:

```css
#pro {
 width:960px;
 display:block;
 margin:0 auto;
}
#pro ul {
 width:100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 text-align: center;
}
#pro li {
 width:33%;
    display: inline-block;
 margin:40px 0;
}
#pro img {
 width:204px;
 height:204px;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 53px 16px rgba(164,207,56,0.29);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 53px 16px rgba(164,207,56,0.29);
 -ms-box-shadow: 0px 0px 53px 16px rgba(164,207,56,0.29);
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 53px 16px rgba(164,207,56,0.29);
 border: 5px solid white;
}
#pro img:hover
 {
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px 16px rgba(0,51,23,1);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px 16px rgba(0,51,23,1);
 -ms-box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px 16px rgba(0,51,23,1);
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px 16px rgba(0,51,23,1);
}
#pro h1 {
 display: table-cell;
 padding:2px;
 background-color:#FFF;
 font-size: 1.5em;
 position: relative;
 top: -40px;
 right:-98px;
 width: 204px;
 -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
 -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
 -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
 transition: all 300ms ease-out;
 opacity:0;
 color:#060;
}
 
#pro li:hover h1 {
 -moz-transform: translateX(-43px);
 -webkit-transform: translateX(-34px);
 -ms-transform: translateX(-43px);
 transform: translateX(-43px);
 opacity:1;
}

#pro h2 {
 margin-top:-55px;
}
#pro a {
 text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
<div id="pro">
     <ul>
      <li>
             <a href="projects/project1/pro1.html"><img src="img/prv1.jpg" alt="project 1"><h1>הכנס לפרוייקט</h1><br><h2>פרוייקט לדוגמא</h2></a></li>
      <li>
             <a href="projects/project2/pro2.html"><img src="img/prv1.jpg" alt="project 1"><h1>הכנס לפרוייקט</h1><br><h2>פרוייקט לדוגמא</h2></a>
            </li>
            <li>
             <a href="projects/project3/pro3.html"><img src="img/prv1.jpg" alt="project 1"><h1>הכנס לפרוייקט</h1><br><h2>פרוייקט לדוגמא</h2></a>
            </li>
            <li>
             <a href="projects/project4/pro4.html"><img src="img/prv1.jpg" alt="project 1"><h1>הכנס לפרוייקט</h1><br><h2>פרוייקט לדוגמא</h2></a>
            </li>
            <li>
             <a href="projects/project5/pro5.html"><img src="img/prv1.jpg" alt="project 1"><h1>הכנס לפרוייקט</h1><br><h2>פרוייקט לדוגמא</h2></a>
            </li>
            <li>
             <a href="projects/project6/pro6.html"><img src="img/prv1.jpg" alt="project 1"><h1>הכנס לפרוייקט</h1><br><h2>פרוייקט לדוגמא</h2></a>
            </li>
            <li>
             <a href="projects/project7/pro7.html"><img src="img/prv1.jpg" alt="project 1"><h1>הכנס לפרוייקט</h1><br><h2>פרוייקט לדוגמא</h2></a>
            </li>
            <li>
             <a href="projects/project8/pro8.html"><img src="img/prv1.jpg" alt="project 1"><h1>הכנס לפרוייקט</h1><br><h2>פרוייקט לדוגמא</h2></a>
            </li>
            <li>
             <a href="projects/project9/pro9.html"><img src="img/prv1.jpg" alt="project 1"><h1>הכנס לפרוייקט</h1><br><h2>פרוייקט לדוגמא</h2></a>
            </li>
         </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: to start off, can you take the h1 and h2 out of the <a href>, its not valid. Make the a href absolute positioned, 100% height/width. possibly try ul width 100%, li width: 33%?

Comment: i did what you said , its half fixed it , now i see 3 pic each line but every browser has his own positioning..
i will update my code now so you can see the changes.

Comment: Once you reset all paddings and margins browsers above ie8 are actually not different

Comment: if i set the a href absolute positioned it making a mess in the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include/Update the below css to get it done!!!

Note: I've removed `display:table-cell; padding:2px;` from the id `#pro h1`.

***The CSS:***

```
h1, h2, ul, li{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#pro h1 {
    background-color: #FFF;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    position: relative;
    top: -80px;
    right: -88px;
    width: 204px;
   -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
   -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
   -ms-rransition: all 300ms ease-out;
   transition: all 300ms ease-out;
   opacity: 0;
   color: #060;
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked!
i made few changes so its will fit right.
thanks alot!!

Answer (score 0):

One thing that I can see is that in your #pro h1 id properties, you've misspelled the word "transition." You've written:

```
-ms-rransition: all 300ms ease-out;
```

It should say:

```
-ms-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
```

Google Chrome might be smart enough to pick up the error, whereas the other browsers might not. Try fixing that first and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
I have changed CSS and it works perfect on Mozilla as well on Chrome.
I hope this will help you.

#pro {
    width:960px;
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto;
}
#pro ul {
    width:100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
#pro li {
    width:33%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin:40px 0;
        position:relative;
}
#pro img {
    width:204px;
    height:204px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 53px 16px rgba(164,207,56,0.29);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 53px 16px rgba(164,207,56,0.29);
    -ms-box-shadow: 0px 0px 53px 16px rgba(164,207,56,0.29);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 53px 16px rgba(164,207,56,0.29);
    border: 5px solid white;
}
#pro img:hover
 {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px 16px rgba(0,51,23,1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px 16px rgba(0,51,23,1);
    -ms-box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px 16px rgba(0,51,23,1);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px 16px rgba(0,51,23,1);
}
#pro h1 {
    display: table-cell;
    padding:2px;
    background-color:#FFF;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 199px;
    right:0px;
    width: 204px;
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    opacity:0;
    color:#060;
}

#pro li:hover h1 {
    -moz-transform: translateX(-43px);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-34px);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-43px);
    transform: translateX(-43px);
    opacity:1;
}

#pro h2 {
    margin-top:-55px;
}
#pro a {
    text-decoration:none;
        float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add display block to this class

```
#pro a {
    display: block; /*** new added***/
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

and add image and sliding h1 in a div